# How can I abort a receive statement in the Erlang shell (erl) without aborting erl?

Tags: erlang

The following makes `erl` hang:

```sh
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:6:6] [ds:6:6:10] [async-threads:1] [jit] [dtrace]

Eshell V12.1  (abort with ^G)
1> receive X -> X end.
```

Hitting ctrl-C brings up a menu of options:

```sh
BREAK: (a)bort (A)bort with dump (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo
```

However, I have not found that any of those returned me to the `erl` prompt. Is the idea that you have to Let It Crash by choosing "(a)bort" and then starting `erl` again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in parentheses right above your shell prompt:

```
(abort with ^G)
```

If you hit ctrl-G, you get a User switch command prompt. You can type `h` at this prompt to see what you can do:

```
User switch command
--> h
 c [nn]            - connect to job
 i [nn]            - interrupt job
 k [nn]            - kill job
 j                 - list all jobs
 s [shell]         - start local shell
 r [node [shell]]  - start remote shell
 q                 - quit erlang
 ? | h             - this message
```

Let's list the jobs:

```
--> j
  1* {shell,start,[init]}
```

That's the shell running your `receive`. You can kill it with `k`, and after that, `j` shows that no jobs are running, so then use `s` to start a new shell, which `j` then shows, and then use `c` to connect to that new shell:

```
--> k 1
--> j
--> s
--> j
  2* {shell,start,[]}
--> c 2
Eshell V12.1  (abort with ^G)
1>
```